# NGINX, как вырезать часть урла?

Tags: nginx

Здравствуйте! need help...
При обращении к 
**www.domainname.com/novosti/i/single-news**
мне нужно направлять посетителя на
**www.domainname.com/news/single-news**
и ставить 301 редирект. Я не понимаю, почему **не** работает вот это:

```
location /novosti/i {
    rewrite ^/novosti/i/(.*)/[^/]+$ /news/$1;
}
```

При использовании такого паттерна при заходе на 
**domainname.com/novosti/i/single-news**
просто перекидывает на главную (

Comment: вообще-то строка `/novosti/i/single-news` **не** подпадает под регулярное выражение `^/novosti/i/(.*)/[^/]+$` потому, что после `/novosti/i/` в ней нет ни одного слэша, что требуется регулярным выражением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что регулярка у Вас лишняя.

```
location = /novosti/i/single-news {
    return 301 $scheme://www.domainname.com/news/single-news;
}
```

Если все-таки у Вас не единственный адрес (в вопросе не совсем понятно) скрывается под адресом www.domainname.com/novosti/i/single-news, а необходим редирект с /novosti/i/ на /news/:

```
location /novosti/i/ {
    rewrite ^/novosti/i/(.*)$ /news/$1 permanent;
}
```